# web svn and safe_mod off conflicts

Tags: php, safe-mode, websvn

I am trying to install websvn but I am getting this error.

```
Warning: proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/xxxxx/public_html/svndirectory/include/command.php on line 173
    Error running this command: svn --config-dir /tmp --version
```

is there any workaround for this?

PS: I cannot turn off php safemode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: http://www.pyrasis.com/repos/websvn/trunk/doc/install.html?view=co

> Also note that WebSVN won't currently work in safe mode, due to the need to call svnlook.